# Difference between smart_close_popup() and cancel_popup() in neocomplete?

Tags: key-bindings, autocompletion, plugin-neocomplete

I have started using neocomplete and there's one thing that confuses me. What's actually the difference between

```
neocomplete#smart_close_popup()
```

and

```
neocomplete#cancel_popup()
```

I am definitely not an expert at vimscript, but to me this looks like they are exactly the same:

```
function! neocomplete#smart_close_popup()
  return neocomplete#mappings#smart_close_popup()
endfunction
```

---

```
function! neocomplete#mappings#smart_close_popup() "{{{
  return neocomplete#mappings#cancel_popup()
endfunction
```

---

```
function! neocomplete#mappings#cancel_popup() "{{{
  let neocomplete = neocomplete#get_current_neocomplete()
  let neocomplete.complete_str = ''
  let neocomplete.skip_next_complete = 1

  return pumvisible() ? "\<C-e>" : ''
endfunction
"}}}
```

I tracked those down in the github repo. Anyway, does `smart_close_popup` just call `cancel_popup`? If yes, is there anything smart about that?

Also, when I do `:map <C-e>` or `:map <C-h>` it says `No mapping found` although I clearly see are bound to stuff (and they do stuff when I test them).

I'd love to get some clarification on this.

Comment: For meaning of `<C-e>` in *popup completion* context, see `:h popupmenu-keys` and scroll down to `CTRL-E`. Also, you don't get `map` results for default Vim key bindings (unless they were set in a script).

Comment: Well `:map <expr><TAB>` and the likes return the same result, even though they are explicitly set in my .vimrc (they were recommended by neocomplete). Why is that?

Comment: Try `:verbose imap <TAB>`

Comment: Thanks for suggesting imap. But about the main question, is smart_close_popup the same as cancel_popup?

Comment: By reading the help, the smart version would regenerate the popup menu, when you press `<BS>`, but only if `g:neocomplete#enable_auto_select` is set to 1. All these functions and options are [documented](https://github.com/Shougo/neocomplete.vim/blob/master/doc/neocomplete.txt).

Comment: Thanks lol. Although playing detective might be a bit fun sometimes, that is so much more convenient. Idk how I missed it (I was on that page)...

Comment: It's ok to dig vimscript :)

Comment: Hey, hey... smart_close_popup doesn't do what it says it does. It doesn't insert the candidate. That's the thing. That's why I looked into it from the beginning. I guess it's some bug, but I still don't get why the function would call another function that calls cancel_popup. You got any idea? Sorry to keep bothering you...

Comment: @Mattias: I propose you open an issue on [neocomplete](https://github.com/Shougo/neocomplete.vim/issues), Shougo tends to be very quick in responding to issues. If you do, please link to the issue (I would be interested in following it).

Comment: there u go: https://github.com/Shougo/neocomplete.vim/issues/463 :)

Comment: @VanLaser is your comment from Aug 16 2015 at 19:08 an answer to this question? If it is, any reason it's not an Answer to this question? I'm a bit new here and trying to figure out why things are done. I'd ask this as a Question in meta, but I don't know that this merits that much of a deal.